# using a DLL from an external vendor that is not thread safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll

I am using a DLL form an external vendor. This DLL is not thread safe, it actual stop with an error messagebox if I try to call its methods from different threads. And I am using the DLL from a larger framework that are using more threads accessing the dll. The threads is not active at the same time, no risk of race conditions.

So the question is; what is the simple way to overcome this? I started to make a wrapper that runs in one special made thread for this that never aborts using ManualResetEvent, waitOne and events. But going through events do not do the trick. How do I make the dll believe that it is only used from one thread?

Comment: You could create a wrapper which `locks` every call to the dll. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: It is a fact of life that most code is thread-unsafe.  Almost any type in the framework is.  Buy the vendor a cigar for him telling you that you're doing it wrong.  He surely can give you better advice than anyone here.  Pick up the phone and give him a call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend coding a wrapper class for your dll.

If you are using .net 4+, you could look into the specialized task schedulers.
Specially this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx

If you don't you can apply the same principle without the TPL. That would be a little more work.

Invoke each fonction from this dll through tasks scheduled on the StaTaskScheduler.

Your dll calls should be fine ;)

Edit:

I guess is that the code should look like this:

```
public class NotThreadSafeClass
{
    public int SomeMethod(string x, int y)
    {
        return 3;
    }
}

public class ThreadSafeWrapper
{
    private TaskScheduler sta = new StaTaskScheduler(numberOfThreads: 1);
    private NotThreadSafeClass old = new NotThreadSafeClass();
    public Task<int> SomeMethod(string x, int y)
    {
        return Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => old.SomeMethod(x,y),
             CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, sta);
    }
}
```

I would keep the awaiting outside of the wrapper if you're in 4+.
Also, the class should be a singleton, to prevent multiple creation that would in the end lead to multiple threads accessing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Hylaean! I am using .net 4 and have started looking into the task schedulers link…If somebody have an example please.

Comment: Thanks again @Hylaean. It is working! I got a bit confused that the wrapper metode return a task when the notThreadSafe return a int, but that is now changes and I am happy. thanks